# Getting the error Reference to uninitialized collection to associative arrays

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql, associative-array

I am using associative arrays in a package I am creating and I get the error ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection if I try to get the count (TBL.COUNT) before I have bulk collected into the array.

I have found that I can use EXISTS(1) to check if there is something there instead of the count but if I am not bulk collecting into it, how do I get the index I need to use for the next row?

```
loc_idx := TBL.COUNT; 
OR  
TBL(TBL.COUNT+1) := blah;
```

My thought was that you didn't need to initialize associative arrays unlike Nested tables and varrays

Here is an example of one I am using

```
TYPE invc_ln_item_type                  IS TABLE OF invc_ln_item%ROWTYPE;
invc_ln_item_tbl                        invc_ln_item_type;
```

used as an input to the following proc

```
    PROCEDURE CREATE_INVC_LN_ITEM(P_LN_ITEM_TYPE_CD IN 
                                  invc_ln_item.ln_item_type_cd%TYPE, 
                                  P_LN_ITEM_SBTYPE_CD IN 
                                  invc_ln_item.ln_item_sbtype_cd%TYPE, 
                                  P_INVC_PK IN invc.invc_pk%TYPE,
                                  P_INVC_LN_ITEM_TBL IN OUT 
                                  invc_ln_item_type)
    IS
    loc_inv_ln_item_rec INVC_LN_ITEM%ROWTYPE;
    loc_idx             NUMBER;
BEGIN

    loc_idx := P_INVC_LN_ITEM_TBL.COUNT + 1;

    INSERT INTO APP.INVC_LN_ITEM (INVC_LN_ITEM_PK, 
                                  INSRT_DT, 
                                  INSRT_USER, 
                                  LAST_UPDT_DT, 
                                  LAST_UPDT_USER, 
                                  LN_ITEM_TYPE_CD, 
                                  LN_ITEM_SBTYPE_CD, 
                                  INVC_PK, 
                                  UNITS, 
                                  AMT)
                          VALUES (null,
                                  null,
                                  null,
                                  null,
                                  null,
                                  P_LN_ITEM_TYPE_CD,
                                  P_LN_ITEM_SBTYPE_CD,
                                  P_INVC_PK,
                                  0,
                                  0)
                        RETURNING INVC_LN_ITEM_PK, 
                                  INSRT_DT, 
                                  INSRT_USER, 
                                  LAST_UPDT_DT, 
                                  LAST_UPDT_USER, 
                                  LN_ITEM_TYPE_CD, 
                                  LN_ITEM_SBTYPE_CD, 
                                  INVC_PK, 
                                  UNITS, 
                                  AMT
                             INTO loc_inv_ln_item_rec; 

    P_INVC_LN_ITEM_TBL(loc_idx) := loc_inv_ln_item_rec;

END;
```

Then gets called like

```
CREATE_INVC_LN_ITEM(P_BILLG_PRFL_LN_ITEM_REC.ln_item_type_cd, 
                                    billg_prfl_ln_item_sbtype_tbl(c).ln_item_sbtype_cd, 
                                    invc_rec.invc_pk,
                                    invc_ln_item_tbl);
```

The errors in the case above occurs at:
    loc_idx := P_INVC_LN_ITEM_TBL.COUNT + 1;

[Error] Execution (39: 1): ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection

Comment: Are you sure that you are using associative array? Please share the code. Edit: why are you using (or trying to use) associative array if your collection will be densely populated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference to uninitialized collection PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201903/reference-to-uninitialized-collection-pl-sql)

Comment: The post listed above is for a nested table.  This post is about a associative array

Comment: If anyone is curioius, I solved this.  When defining the TYPE, I forgot the: INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER

Comment: @programmerNOOB `When defining the TYPE, I forgot the: INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER` then your collection no more existed as associative array. it got converted to nested table and that's why above link was posted for you. Also error like `Reference to uninitialized collection PL/SQL` occurs only with Nested tables coz in Associative arrays we donot need to intialize anything. So actually that was a pointer which ` Goran Stefanović` pointed very well,

Answer (score 0):

There is not an incrementing index for an associative array. You do not need to initialise an associative array and using `array.COUNT` will not raise an exception with an associative array (unlike for collections).

```
DECLARE
  TYPE arraytype IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(2);

  array arraytype;
  idx VARCHAR2(2);
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( array.COUNT ); -- 0
  array('A') := 'AAAA';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( array.COUNT ); -- 1
  array(array.COUNT + 1) := 'BBBB';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( array.COUNT ); -- 2
  array('7') := 'DDDD';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( array.COUNT ); -- 3

  idx := array.FIRST;
  WHILE idx IS NOT NULL LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( idx || ' - ' || array(idx) );
    idx := array.NEXT( idx );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

If you are expecting to use an incrementing index then you need to consider whether an associative array is the correct type to be using and whether a collection or a VARRAY would be better.

If you are using collections (not associative arrays):

```
DECLARE
  TYPE arraytype IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);

  array arraytype;
BEGIN
  array := arraytype(); -- Initialise
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( array.COUNT ); -- 0
  array.EXTEND;                        -- Extend by 1 element
  array(1) := 'AAAA';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( array.COUNT ); -- 1
  array.EXTEND(1);                     -- Number of elements to extend by
  array(array.COUNT) := 'BBBB';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( array.COUNT ); -- 2
  array.EXTEND;
  array(3) := 'DDDD';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( array.COUNT ); -- 3

  FOR idx IN 1 .. array.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( idx || ' - ' || array(idx) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: This was my thoughts as well, So I am just wondering how I am getting this.  I have defined the AAs at the spec level and they are passed around to procs within the package.  Could that have something to do with it?  I will try to add more substance to the original post